# Part identification: [CSC2822]

Tags: components, identification, dip

I took apart this old, white alarm clock and there's a small, DIP-8 IC in there with "HWCAT 714C6A CSC2822" written on it. I've tried searching for a datasheet, but I can't find one. I can find some references to the part itself (on some Chinese parts sources), but nothing about what it is or how it can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [site](http://www.hwcat.com/EN/ProductsList.aspx?id=16&cid=2) in the other answer I discovered its an opamp for audio. Here is the information I got:

> HWD02 CSC 2822P/2822m 双声道功率放大
>   TDA2822P/TDA2822M DIP8/SOP8

Then I recognised the TDA2822 to be some form of audio opamp and you can pull a datasheet from another manufacturer. Here is the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000134.pdf) from STs version.

双声道功率放大 translates to: Two-channel power amplifier this just confirms that its a reproduction of the original part.

Comment: Interesting. What still has me confused, though, is that pins 1 and 3 of the TDA2822 are the outputs, but in this circuit those lines go directly to the positive and negative pins of the speakers...

Comment: @Voithos That could be to do with that part so they don't have to pay royalties. Check other manufactures see if they have the the same pin layout.

Comment: @voithos It seems quite natural to me that the power amplifier outputs (1 and 3) are connected directly to the speakers. Could you explain why do you find it confusing?

Answer (score 2):

HWCAT seems to have a web site and have a contact us section there. You could try contacting them for a datasheet. http://www.hwcat.com/EN/ProductsList.aspx?id=21&cid=2

Looking at their product nomenclature, I am tempted to think of the 8 pin DIP IC as a clone of the uA741 operational amplifier.

What part of the circuit did you find the IC? What other components was it connected to. Does the circuit make sens if you assume it's pinout to be that of uA741?

Comment: I looked up the UA741, and it seems that pin 1 is Offset null and pin 3 is a non-inverting input. I don't think this would make sense here, as pins 1 and 3 are connected to the negative and positive lines of the speakers. But I may just be stupid.

Comment: @voithos - It was just a guess. Did the TDA2822P/TDA2822M solution posted by @Dean work?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be condescending. As for Dean's reply, see my comment.